# Turn iOS project to OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

what is the easiest and fastest way to turn iOS project to work on OSX. I've already added OSX to project, and tried to use ios storboard. But it just load empty window. Is there any simply, tricky way to do this? I dont want to rebuild entire UI, and link all outlets, etc..

Comment: Just to callout the difference between iOS and OSX, just have a look at how `NSCollectionView` works on OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although quite similar in some respect, iOS and OS X are completely different when it comes to interface. Main difference being that `UIKit` doesn't exist on OS X meaning that your UI isn't compatible with OS X.

All your UI code will need to be started from scratch but most of the backing logic should be ok depending on how you've architectured your application.

As mentioned by [Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304242/mikael) in the comments, [AppKit for UIKit Developers](http://www.objc.io/issue-14/appkit-for-uikit-developers.html) is a great article for iOS Developers looking to expand onto OS X.

Also, [Separated at birth: Why Apple won't merge OS X and iOS](http://www.macworld.com/article/2097721/separated-at-birth-why-apple-wont-merge-os-x-and-ios.html) is also another good article to give you a better understanding on why it works like this.

Comment: I agree with the answer. This is a great article with a deeper look: http://www.objc.io/issue-14/appkit-for-uikit-developers.html